# How to use setfacl on ZFS dataset to set the equivalent of UNIX-style chmod 770?

Tags: samba, zfs, access-control-list, truenas, setfacl

I'm trying to use `setfacl` to set the permissions of different ZFS datasets, and I want those ACL permissions equivalent to UNIX-style `chmod 770`.

What `setfacl` command could accomplish this, and what ACLs should `getfacl` display if I were to do this correctly?

I'm running FreeNAS 11.0 with Samba 4.6.4.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me to find out that it's not possible to do the equivalent of `chmod 770` with ACLs, since the solution already exists:  `chmod 770`.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: the following is from a Solaris system, but the results should also work on BSD (where you need to use `getfacl`/`setfacl` instead of `ls`/`chmod`).*

---

The default permissions of a newly created (text) **file** are:

```
   owner@:rw-p--aARWcCos:-------:allow
   group@:r-----a-R-c--s:-------:allow
everyone@:r-----a-R-c--s:-------:allow
```

If you use `chmod 0770 /path/to/file`, you will get:

```
   owner@:rwxp--aARWcCos:-------:allow
   group@:rwxp--a-R-c--s:-------:allow
everyone@:------a-R-c--s:-------:allow
```

Essentially, execute (x) is added for owner and group, read (r) is removed from everyone, and write (w) and append (p) are added to group.

---

For a **directory**, it looks as follows:

```
   owner@:rwxp-DaARWcCos:-------:allow
   group@:r-x---a-R-c--s:-------:allow
everyone@:r-x---a-R-c--s:-------:allow
```

And after modification:

```
   owner@:rwxp-DaARWcCos:-------:allow
   group@:rwxp-Da-R-c--s:-------:allow
everyone@:------a-R-c--s:-------:allow
```

Here, read (r) and execute (x) are removed from everyone, while owner and group have the same permissions as in the file case, although with added delete_child (D) permission (this comes from being a directory).

Comment: So, on FreeNAS, the existence of ACLs on files and directories seems to completely invalidate the `chmod` command. So my question is about what flags to use in `setfacl`, because `chmod` doesn't work to modify ACLs in this way. So, thank you for laying out what the ACLs should be, but I still don't understand what flags should be included in `setfacl` to set them as such. I'm just finding the `setfacl` `man` page really inaccessible.